# Construction function initial list, what this code means?

Tags: c++, class

The code is this:

```
MemTable::MemTable(const InternalKeyComparator& cmp)
: comparator_(cmp),
  refs_(0),
  table_(comparator_, &arena_) {
}
```

I know for

```
comparator_(cmp)
```

that cmp will be given to comparator_, but for

```
table_(comparator_, &arena_)
```

what is to be done?

Comment: It's calling the constructor of `table_` with those arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
comparator_(cmp)
```

> that cmp will be given to comparator_

More accurately, this means the constructor of `comparator_` will be called with the argument `cmp`. So

```
table_(comparator_, &arena_)
```

just means the constructor of `table_` will be called with the two arguments `(comparator_, &arena_)`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the initialiser list is executed before the body of the constructor. The initialiser list calls the constructors of the members of the class which are mentioned in it, passing to those constructors parameters from this class's constructor, or this class's members. You don't mention where "arena_" comes from, but it looks like it's another member of your class.